Convert Invoke-RestMethod to axios request
I am using powershell to make rest requests to onprem Sharepoint Server.  I am required to use Windows domain credentials for authentication, and I'm currently using that coupled with a digest returned from an endpoint.
The command is:
Invoke-RestMethod -uri {{uri}} -method {{method}} -CurrentCredentials
The above works for any request I make (provided headers are right - include updated digest, etc).
I want to emulate this request, but with axios.  However, whenever I make the request with axios (or anything else including curl), I get 401.  I’m using -withcredentials with axios, but I get 401 even when requesting digest.
My basic question is how can I emulate the underlying request powershell makes when using the “currentcredentials” switch?  I’m assuming that’s what’s wrong, but I don’t see anything useful in the response to point me in any direction.
How to speak the above pwsh command in javascript using node with axios?
Edit:  shouldn’t matter, but enterprise 2019 Sharepoint on prem is what I’m using.
